# MIME Types requirements

Tags: fiware-orion

(Moved from https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/2343)

I have doubt concerning the MIME types requirement:

In [the NGSIv2 spec](http://fiware.github.io/specifications/ngsiv2/stable/) we have in the section MIME Types the following:

> the response payloads other than application/json and test/plain are not accepted.

Although the MIME types requierement was only mentioned on the following operation:

- section: Attribute Value, operation: Get attribute value
- section: Attribute Value, operation: Update attribute value

So does the MIME Types requierement shall be taken into consideration in all requests having a payload response or only on the operations mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "MIME Types" section defines the general rules that apply to the overall API. Thus, the types supported by the API are application/json and text/plain. No other type (e.g. application/xml) is supported in any operation.

More specifically, most of the operations support only application/json (detailo in the NGSIv2 spec itself). Only the operations related with attribute values (the ones you mention: "Get attribute value" and "Update attribute value") allows also text/plain.

Comment: Does this means that if I want to list all entities, in the Get request I have to specify the header "Accept=application/json", and if I specify a wrong header such "Accept=application/xml" or if I dont specify at all I shall get the error "406 :Not Acceptable"? if yes it is not the implented behavior in Orion version 1.2

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the Orion version you are using, please? i.e. the output of the `contextBroker --version` command, including version number an githash. Thanks!

Comment: I have realized that "your post" is actually "my post" xD, as the question was moved from github. Not sure if you have edition permission on my post... in negative case please provide that information as comment.

Comment: I edites the post but I think it takes time to validate the edites. while waiting for the edit validation, here is the version: "version": "1.2.0",
    "git_hash": "4145b4d231b1a5c3e68d068527eab156f97413ca",